# Access an application running on NodePort of minikube inside an EC2 instance from outside world

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes, minikube, istio

I have an EC2 instance say its IP is 44.XX.XX.XX (Say IP1), I have an minikube which is running inside this EC2 instance say its  IP is 10.XX.XX.XX (Say IP2) , which I came to know by doing minikube ip inside EC2 instance . I have an Frontend application running inside minikube at NodePort say 30010 . I am able to curl to application by doing
curl http://IP2:30010

But I want to access this application out side ec2 through any other PC . How to do this , I tried doing http://IP1:30010 but it didnit work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming this is only for development purpose? You need to port forward the traffic from your EC2 node to minikube as minikube runs as separate VM.

Once you have kubectl setup on the IP2 host machine talking to the minikube cluster, you can use [kubectl port-forward](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) to forward traffic to any service/pod running inside minikube.

`kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 svc/<svc-name> <host-port>:<service-port>`

You should be able to access your app at `IP2:<host-port>` as long as the port-forwarding is set up.

(Replace stuff within `< >` brackets with appropriate values)

Comment: From my testing, this solution works but interestingly does not seem to require the NodePort service -- in fact it ignores the NodePort port and just uses the application port. In fact you can skip creation of the NodePort service entirely and use this solution passing in `deployment/<dep-name>` to the command.

Answer (score 0):

minikube: Running in the background

```
$ kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 svc/<Service-Name> --namespace <NameSpace Name> 31000:20001 & 

$ netstat -anplt | grep 31000
```

Now, you can access the port **31000** on your browser,

http://localhost:31000